# How to increase recovery partition size?

Tags: adb, recovery-mode, twrp, partitions

I'm totally lost right now.
I want to flash TWRP 3.7 on my Galaxy S7 herolte. However, it won't work because the recovery partition is only 46MB. So I wanted to increase the size - a process I've done many times before, but I can't figure out how to get information on the recovery partition.

```
# df -h
Filesystem                   Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
rootfs                       1.6G  4.4M  1.5G   1% /
tmpfs                        1.7G  444K  1.7G   1% /dev
tmpfs                        1.7G     0  1.7G   0% /mnt
/dev/block/sda14             4.0G  1.3G  2.7G  33% /system
/dev/block/sda3               16M  3.0M   13M  20% /efs
/dev/block/sda15             193M  168K  193M   1% /cache
/dev/block/sda18              25G  1.4G   23G   6% /data
/dev/block/sda13             4.8M  160K  4.6M   4% /persdata/absolute
tmpfs                        1.7G     0  1.7G   0% /storage
/data/media                   25G  1.4G   23G   6% /mnt/runtime/default/emulated
/data/media                   25G  1.4G   23G   6% /storage/emulated
/data/media                   25G  1.4G   23G   6% /mnt/runtime/read/emulated
/data/media                   25G  1.4G   23G   6% /mnt/runtime/write/emulated
/dev/block/vold/public:179_1  60G  719M   59G   2% /mnt/media_rw/0000-0000
/mnt/media_rw/0000-0000       60G  719M   59G   2% /mnt/runtime/default/0000-0000
/mnt/media_rw/0000-0000       60G  719M   59G   2% /storage/0000-0000
/mnt/media_rw/0000-0000       60G  719M   59G   2% /mnt/runtime/read/0000-0000
/mnt/media_rw/0000-0000       60G  719M   59G   2% /mnt/runtime/write/0000-0000
```

```
# cat /proc/mounts
rootfs / rootfs rw,seclabel,size=1680604k,nr_inodes=420151 0 0
tmpfs /dev tmpfs rw,seclabel,nosuid,relatime,size=1816696k,nr_inodes=454174,mode=755 0 0
devpts /dev/pts devpts rw,seclabel,relatime,mode=600 0 0
proc /proc proc rw,relatime,gid=3009,hidepid=2 0 0
sysfs /sys sysfs rw,seclabel,relatime 0 0
selinuxfs /sys/fs/selinux selinuxfs rw,relatime 0 0
/sys/kernel/debug /sys/kernel/debug debugfs rw,seclabel,relatime 0 0
none /acct cgroup rw,relatime,cpuacct 0 0
tmpfs /mnt tmpfs rw,seclabel,relatime,size=1816696k,nr_inodes=454174,mode=755,gid=1000 0 0
none /config configfs rw,relatime 0 0
none /dev/cpuctl cgroup rw,relatime,cpu 0 0
none /dev/cpuset cgroup rw,relatime,cpuset,noprefix,release_agent=/sbin/cpuset_release_agent 0 0
pstore /sys/fs/pstore pstore rw,seclabel,relatime 0 0
/dev/block/platform/155a0000.ufs/by-name/SYSTEM /system ext4 ro,seclabel,relatime,norecovery,errors=panic 0 0
/dev/block/platform/155a0000.ufs/by-name/EFS /efs ext4 rw,seclabel,nosuid,nodev,noatime,discard,journal_checksum,journal_async_commit,noauto_da_alloc,data=ordered 0 0
/dev/block/platform/155a0000.ufs/by-name/CACHE /cache ext4 rw,seclabel,nosuid,nodev,noatime,discard,journal_checksum,journal_async_commit,noauto_da_alloc,errors=panic,data=ordered 0 0
/dev/block/platform/155a0000.ufs/by-name/USERDATA /data ext4 rw,seclabel,nosuid,nodev,noatime,discard,journal_checksum,journal_async_commit,noauto_da_alloc,errors=panic,data=ordered 0 0
/dev/block/platform/155a0000.ufs/by-name/PERSDATA /persdata/absolute ext4 rw,seclabel,nosuid,nodev,noatime,journal_checksum,journal_async_commit,noauto_da_alloc 0 0
tmpfs /storage tmpfs rw,seclabel,relatime,size=1816696k,nr_inodes=454174,mode=755,gid=1000 0 0
/data/media /mnt/runtime/default/emulated sdcardfs rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,noatime,fsuid=1023,fsgid=1023,gid=1015,multiuser,mask=6 0 0
/data/media /storage/emulated sdcardfs rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,noatime,fsuid=1023,fsgid=1023,gid=1015,multiuser,mask=6 0 0
/data/media /mnt/runtime/read/emulated sdcardfs rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,noatime,fsuid=1023,fsgid=1023,gid=9997,multiuser,mask=23 0 0
/data/media /mnt/runtime/write/emulated sdcardfs rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,noatime,fsuid=1023,fsgid=1023,gid=9997,multiuser,mask=7 0 0
/dev/block/vold/public:179_1 /mnt/media_rw/0000-0000 fuseblk rw,dirsync,nosuid,nodev,noexec,noatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,default_permissions,allow_other,blksize=4096 0 0
/mnt/media_rw/0000-0000 /mnt/runtime/default/0000-0000 sdcardfs rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,noatime,fsuid=1023,fsgid=1023,gid=1015,mask=6 0 0
/mnt/media_rw/0000-0000 /storage/0000-0000 sdcardfs rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,noatime,fsuid=1023,fsgid=1023,gid=1015,mask=6 0 0
/mnt/media_rw/0000-0000 /mnt/runtime/read/0000-0000 sdcardfs rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,noatime,fsuid=1023,fsgid=1023,gid=9997,mask=18 0 0
/mnt/media_rw/0000-0000 /mnt/runtime/write/0000-0000 sdcardfs rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,noatime,fsuid=1023,fsgid=1023,gid=9997,mask=18 0 0
```

```
# cat /proc/partitions
major minor  #blocks  name

   8        0   31232000 sda
   8        1       4096 sda1
   8        2       4096 sda2
   8        3      20480 sda3
   8        4       8192 sda4
   8        5      40960 sda5
   8        6      47104 sda6
   8        7       8192 sda7
   8        8      43008 sda8
   8        9       1024 sda9
   8       10       1024 sda10
   8       11        768 sda11
   8       12        256 sda12
   8       13       9216 sda13
   8       14    4403200 sda14
   8       15     204800 sda15
 259        0      61440 sda16
 259        1       5120 sda17
 259        2   26357760 sda18
   8       16       4096 sdb
   8       32       4096 sdc
   8       48       8192 sdd
   8       49       6144 sdd1
 179        0   62521344 mmcblk0
 179        1   62504960 mmcblk0p1
```

```
# ls -ahl /dev/block/platform/155a0000.ufs/by-name/
total 0
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 420 2023-03-03 11:51 .
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root 540 2023-03-03 11:51 ..
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  15 2023-03-03 11:51 BOOT -> /dev/block/sda5
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  15 2023-03-03 11:51 BOTA0 -> /dev/block/sda1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  15 2023-03-03 11:51 BOTA1 -> /dev/block/sda2
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  16 2023-03-03 11:51 CACHE -> /dev/block/sda15
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  15 2023-03-03 11:51 CPEFS -> /dev/block/sdd1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  16 2023-03-03 11:51 CP_DEBUG -> /dev/block/sda17
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  16 2023-03-03 11:51 DNT -> /dev/block/sda10
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  15 2023-03-03 11:51 EFS -> /dev/block/sda3
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  16 2023-03-03 11:51 HIDDEN -> /dev/block/sda16
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  15 2023-03-03 11:51 OTA -> /dev/block/sda7
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  15 2023-03-03 11:51 PARAM -> /dev/block/sda4
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  16 2023-03-03 11:51 PERSDATA -> /dev/block/sda13
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  16 2023-03-03 11:51 PERSISTENT -> /dev/block/sda11
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  15 2023-03-03 11:51 RADIO -> /dev/block/sda8
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  15 2023-03-03 11:51 RECOVERY -> /dev/block/sda6
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  16 2023-03-03 11:51 STEADY -> /dev/block/sda12
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  16 2023-03-03 11:51 SYSTEM -> /dev/block/sda14
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  15 2023-03-03 11:51 TOMBSTONES -> /dev/block/sda9
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  16 2023-03-03 11:51 USERDATA -> /dev/block/sda18
```

```
# parted /dev/block/mmcblk0 print
Model: SD 00000 (sd/mmc)
Disk /dev/block/mmcblk0: 64.0GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos

Number  Start   End     Size    Type     File system  Flags
 1      16.8MB  64.0GB  64.0GB  primary
```

I was expecting to see sda6 in the output of parted and just be able to change the size of the partition. Any ideas what I'm missing?

For searchability, the original bug that brought me to the idea:

> Size of image is larger than target device

Comment: Tangential to your question, but [discussion on XDA Forum about 3.7.0 being too large](https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/recovery-exynos-official-twrp-for-galaxy-s7-herolte.3333770/post-87562941), which also suggested [Ivan's fixed build](https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/recovery-exynos-official-twrp-for-galaxy-s7-herolte.3333770/post-87570457) which is only 43MB, and also [a short-but-complete guide](https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/recovery-exynos-official-twrp-for-galaxy-s7-herolte.3333770/post-87977005)

Comment: @AndrewT. Thx, that solved my initial issue